# How to define non-reserved key words with antlr

Tags: sql, antlr, keyword

I'm using antlr to analyse and re-write sql query.

I have:

```
select : SELECT ;

fragment S : 's' | 'S' ;
....
fragment LETTER : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' ;

SELECT : S E L E C T ;

IDENTIFIER : LETTER+ ;
```

to define reserved key words and let them to be case-insensitive.

My question is how can I define non-reserved key words?

Comment: What's a non reserved keyword? I thought you meant an IDENTIFIER, but you already have such a rule...

Comment: Belowe is what I found at http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql3bnf.sep93.txt

Comment: <reserved word> ::=
      ABSOLUTE | ACTION | ACTOR | ADD | AFTER | ALIAS
    | ALL | ALLOCATE | ALTER
<non-reserved word> ::=
      ADA
    | C | CATALOG_NAME
    | CHAIN
    | CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG | CHARACTER_SET_NAME

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. I don't see how defining a none-reserved word is any different than defining a keyword. Have you taken a look at the various SQL-dialects posted on the ANTLR wiki: http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list ?

Comment: I have a same kind of problem , if i use a word as a keyword, I will not be able to use that word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems similar to the problem we had when building the parser for the Drools (www.jboss.org/drools) language (DRL). In DRL, for instance, "rule" is a keyword, but could also be used by a java programmer as a property name in his POJO. So we can't have that as a reserved keyword.

```
rule /*keyword*/ "my rule"
when
    SomeClass( rule /*property name*/ == "foo" )
...
```

We called these keywords "soft keywords".

To do that in ANTLR, we defined only "true"/"false"/"null" as hard keywords in the LEXER:

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/main/resources/org/drools/lang/DRLLexer.g#L132

Everything else is an ID. Then in the PARSER, we used semantic predicates for each soft keyword:

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/main/resources/org/drools/lang/DRLExpressions.g#L597

This makes it possible to seamlessly integrate with java created POJOs without clashing property names and other things with Drools defined keywords.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The given links are broken :(. Perhaps the links should be changed to DRL5Lexer.g/DRL5Expressions.g or DRL6Lexer.g/DRL6Expressions.g?